# Remove legend labels using label = FALSE in guide_legend, or labels = NULL in discrete_scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

As a part of a more complex plot with several legends, one of the legends has only one entry. I want to remove the label from this particular legend and keep only the (edited) title.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = factor(x))) + 
       geom_point()
p
```

[image]

Because I do some other manipulations of the legends using `guides(foo = guide_legend(override.aes`, I was hoping to remove the labels in the same `guide_legend` call using the `label` argument.

From `?guide.legend`:
"`label`: [...] If `FALSE` then the labels are invisible."

Thus, I tried:

```
p + guides(color = guide_legend(title = "other",
                                label = FALSE))
```

But this gives an error:

```
# Error in (function (name)  : grob 'NULL' not found
```

I then had a look at `discrete_scale`, which has a `labels` argument (now with an "s"). From `?discrete_scale`:
"`labels`: `NULL` for no labels."

Thus, I tried:

```
p + scale_color_discrete(name = "other",
                         labels = NULL)
```

...which generates an error:

```
# Error in data.frame(values = scale_map(scale, breaks), labels = I(scale_labels(scale)),  : 
#                      arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

My current workaround is:

```
p + scale_color_discrete(name = "other",
                         labels = "")
```

However, as described above, I would prefer to remove the labels using `guide_legend` call.

So my main question is:
How can I make `label = FALSE` in `guide_legend` work?

If the answer is "*it's just doesn't work*", how is the "`labels`: `NULL` for no labels." supposed to be used in `scale_foo_bar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `label = FALSE` in `guide_legend` and `labels = NULL` in `discrete_scale` are fixed in the development version `ggplot2_1.0.1.9002`.

```
# install development version, see https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/.
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("hadley/scales")
devtools::install_github("hadley/ggplot2movies")
devtools::install_github("hadley/ggplot2")

p + guides(color = guide_legend(title = "other", label = FALSE))
# or:
# p + scale_color_discrete(name = "other", labels = NULL)
```

[image]